# JQuery - Sliding

Tags: jquery

I saw [this website](http://www.mindthree.com/) in this when we click the next or previous buttons it slides different webpages. I want the same effect but I could not find the way to do it. Can you post the answer with HTML, CSS and JQuery or Javascript code.

Comment: No; first: undertake some research, and inspect the source-html of the page, inspect the various elements with your browser's development tools and then try and work out what's happening. Then ask about those things that confuse you, or that you don't understand.

Comment: @DavidThomas Do not be so strict! Who asks like him, will never learn it ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here, just one approach!

**HTML**

```
<div id="item1" class="page"><a href="#item2">1</a></div>
<div id="item2" class="page"><a href="#item3">2</a></div>
<div id="item3" class="page"><a href="#item4">3</a></div>
<div id="item4" class="page"><a href="#item1">4</a></div>
```

**CSS**

```
html, body {height:100%; margin:0; overflow-y:hidden}
.page {position:absolute; width:100%; height:100%}
#item1 {left:0%; background:#222}
#item2 {left:100%; background:#444}
#item3 {left:200%; background:#666}
#item4 {left:300%; background:#888}
```

**JS**

```
$(function() {
    $('a[href*=#]').on('click', function(e) {
        var hash = $(this.hash).position();
        if (hash) {
            $('html, body').stop().animate({
                scrollLeft: hash.left
            }, 600, 'swing');
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: but it don't scrolls like that!

Comment: Give `easing` a try... Google a bit and you will find what you want!

Comment: Vote up and mark your question as answered, if it is!

Answer (score 1):

Just make a **super-wide** website, and then use **Javascript** to scroll to the next section.

Using a framework may be a solution for you. Check this [**link**](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2010/06/02/smooth-vertical-or-horizontal-page-scrolling-with-jquery/)